# Construct a real matrix from a system of three differential equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

[image]

Could anyone please explain it to me what this question demands me to do? Thank you.
(I am aware I need to proof I have tried with my effort before asking a question, but I really have no idea where I should begin)

Follow-up: Now I have obtained eigenvalues of 1,-2+ root(-36) and -2-root (-36)

Updates: My eigen-vectors of A is a 3x3 identity matrix

Comment: $U^{-1} A U = J$

Comment: So, I should find U by getting eigenvalues and vectors of A?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ and $J$ are both diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues, there are matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that
$$
P^{-1}AP = D = Q^{-1}JQ,
$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why is there Q? And do you mind use Letters according to the question please? Adding more letter confuses me even more.

Comment: @Complicated Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: I sort of do, but it's always confusing for me.